# Tabular multicolumn cell boundaries

Tags: tables

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}           
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
            \hline 
            1  & 2  & 3\tabularnewline 
            \hline 
            4  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{5}  \tabularnewline
            \hline 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

It produces the table:

[image]

> How do I "close" the cell (add the right boundary as in the line above)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell multicolumn to use those vertical lines.

[image: cell]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}           
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
            \hline 
            1  & 2  & 3\\\hline 
            4  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{5}\\\hline 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```